# Postgres - ranking with additional conditions, then pulling the top 3 results

Tags: postgresql

I want to combine 2 conditions and get the top 3 rank result.

My dataset has 2 components, i.e. 1 major group and with sub-groups mapping to each major group

For e.g. i take part of the dataset for Group A

```
Group | Sub-group | Revenue | Source
---------------------------------------
A     |     A-1   |  50     |  Y
A     |     A-2   |  40     |  Y
A     |     A-3   |  60     |  Y 
A     |     A-4   |  80     |  Y
A     |     A-5   |  100    |  Y
A     |     A-6   |  140    |  X
A     |     A-7   |  20     |  X
A     |     A-8   |  300    |  X
```

And under Revenue, there are different sources, such as revenue from source X and source Y. I am only interested at source Y.

So I want to pull get a list of eligible results, with top 3 revenue > rank them. A separate step to pull data of Group A for sub-groups that have revenue from source Y. My steps:

```
    WITH
      sum_revenue AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          subgroup,
          SUM(revenue) AS total_rev
        FROM table t
        GROUP BY 1, 2
      ),
      subgroup_rev AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          total_rev,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY group ORDER BY total_rev DESC
            )
            AS row
        FROM sum_revenue
        GROUP BY 1, 2
        ),
      source_rev AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          subgroup,
          SUM(revenue) AS total_sourceY_rev
        FROM table t
        WHERE
          subgroup = 'Y'
        GROUP BY 1, 2
      ),
      eligible AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          subgroup,
          total_revenue,
          FROM source_rev
          WHERE total_sourceY_rev < 1  --identify top 3 revenue with source Y rev < $1
        ),
      agg_list AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          STRING_AGG(DISTINCT eligible.subgroup) AS eligible_list
          INNER JOIN eligible USING (group) 
        WHERE subgroup_rev.row <= 3
        GROUP BY 1
       )
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          eligible_list
        FROM agg_list
        WHERE group IN ('A')
```

I'm expecting to get aggregated list of top 3 revenue of subgroup which fulfils the condition with source Y revenue <$1.
)
But I am getting full list (or partial list aggregated (not top 3), my result gave me 7. I tried running without aggregate and it did return 7 individual rows as well.

what could have gone wrong ? I thought i have filtered with row <=3, and I also tried with `INNER JOIN` when i thought i might introduced redundant subgroup if using LEFT JOIN.

seems to be issue with joining with `eligible` alias, because when i break down to test with pulling directly from `subgroup_rev` without joining `eligible`, i can get the top 3 revenue subgroups.

However, I need the condition with the subgroups having source Y revenue, that are having highest 3, so ideally i shouldn't hardcode row as `3` (because some cases the some of the top 3s might not necessarily have source Y revenue.

[EDIT] based on feedback
Result:

```
   Group | eligible_list
    ---------------------------
    A     | A-1,A-2,A-3,A-4,A-5
```

Expected result:

```
 Group | eligible_list
---------------------------
 A     | A-3,A-4,A-5
```

Comment: Please show us the result you want for this sample data. Your data has no notion of `source` and no `'Y'` in it, which makes the question unclear. Also, `STRING_AGG()` is not a thing in MySQL, are you sure this is the database you are running?

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I further edited to correct and adding in details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restructured my funnel of data and finally got it work:

```html
    WITH
    source_rev AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          subgroup,
          SUM(revenue) AS total_sourceY_rev
        FROM table t
        WHERE
          subgroup = 'Y'
        GROUP BY 1, 2
      ),
      eligible AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          subgroup,
          total_revenue,
          FROM source_rev
          WHERE total_sourceY_rev < 1  --identify top 3 revenue with source Y rev < $1
        ),
      sum_revenue AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          subgroup,
          SUM(revenue) AS total_rev
        FROM table t
        INNER JOIN eligible
        USING (group)
        GROUP BY 1, 2
      ),
      subgroup_rev AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          subgroup,
          sum_revenue.total_rev,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY group ORDER BY sum_revenue.total_rev DESC
            )
            AS row
        FROM eligible
        INNER JOIN sum_revenue
        USING (group)
        GROUP BY 1, 2,3
        ),
      agg_list AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          STRING_AGG(DISTINCT eligible.subgroup) AS eligible_list
        WHERE subgroup_rev.row <= 3
        GROUP BY 1
       )
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          eligible_list
        FROM agg_list
        WHERE group IN ('A')
```

The difference is that

- i first narrow the data with revenue from source Y and
- find those eligible data with conditional select
- then i am having an alias that pull total revenue of all source and finally `INNER JOIN` them together
- do the ranking, so that the ranking is only being performed on the eligible data (i.e. source Y revenue < $1), and finally
- aggregating them.

Result with eligible list with source Y revenue < $1:

```
 Group | eligible_list
---------------------------
 A     | A-3,A-4,A-5
```

I note that some share feedback with me of having too many subgroups. Happy to get any other feedback for a better way to do this if there's more efficient suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be your `subgroup_rev` subquery.
Since you are using a `OVER` with a `PARTITION` as well as a `GROUP BY` clause, you may just end of creating groups for each combination of group and subgroup. I believe your `subgroup_rev` subquery can just be:

```
      subgroup_rev AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          group,
          total_rev,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY group ORDER BY total_rev DESC
            )
            AS row
        FROM sum_revenue)
```

Like @GMB said, it's hard to follow without seeing how sources play into the revenue column, but too much grouping may ruin your rankings.

You may end up with a all groups having only 1 member so all of their rankings would be 1 and thus would all be returned in by your final `WHERE` clause.

Comment: thanks trip for your input! I tried but seems to return the same result, I am working on swapping my logic to funnel down the data differently to see if that works. I have to use subgroups because i need to do different conditions (total revenue of all source for the ranking; filtered revenue by source Y and access if those are < $1 for the eligibility)